# grails render tag: can't find file unless it's located in src/templates/scaffolding?

Tags: grails, gsp

I tried to follow the example under "Shared Templates" here:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.3%20Views%20and%20Templates

But this just plain didn't work.  The tag I used was:

```
<g:render template="/includes/mySearch"></g:render>
```

I created a directory under the views called "includes" and created a gsp file, with a very basic form in it, named mySearch.gsp.

However, grails reported being unable to find the file:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\grails-1.3.7\src\grails\templates\scaffolding_mySearch.gsp

According to the documentation: "In this case you can place them in the root views directory at grails-app/views or any subdirectory below that location and then with the template attribute use a / before the template name to indicate the relative template path."

It would appear that this is exactly what I did, but grails was not looking there?  Any advice?

Many thanks,
Alexx

Comment: my question was more to the effect of, why is the framework looking in \scaffolding, and not \includes?

Answer (score 1):

Template files need to be starting with an underscore. Therefore you need to rename your `mySearch.gsp` to `_mySearch.gsp`.